# How do I fix Adobe Sign telling me there is no internet connection

Tags: proxy, web-filtering

We use a proxy that blocks by content type and it was blocking something Acrobat needed for the "request signature" function.

After talking with Adobe, they were unable to tell us which of the 50 URLs they used for this service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After calling Adobe a 2nd time, they provided a different list of endpoints that was actually helpful.

You will need to whitelist everything in the `send for signature` section: https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/endpoints.html

If you use a PAC file you need to add wildcard conditions to your `if` statement.  Example:

```
shExpMatch(host, "*.acrobat.com")
```